# How can I fix this 'Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error: Expected id but found open_square in'

Tags: syntax-error, jekyll, liquid

I just started running my blog using Github pages.
I chose 'minimal mistakes' theme and encountered a problem while customizing.

```
{% assign posts = site.categories.['Effective Java'] %}
```

The reason why I used square bracket is because of the blank between 'Effective' and 'Java'.
It actually works well without any problems, but I don't want to see the Liquid Warning any more.
Is there a better way to deal with the blank?

Comment: `{% assign posts = site.categories['Effective Java'] %}` you do have an extra dot before your square bracket.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you! Warning is gone!